# Checking textfield value for date in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsdate

I used 3 textfield(string) and 1 button for display entered textfield in soap result.

When clicked button

```
TextField1=StationID --> 12345                    
TextField2 =FirstDate --> 07.05.2013
TextField3=LastDate  ---> 08.05.2013
```

searching and display somethings etc etc

I want to check date processes.For example it must be LastDate > FirstDate.If entered FirstDate > LastDate give error
If user entered like 30.02.2014 dates to firstdate and lastdate it must have give error.February has not 30 days.``

How can I do this ??

Comment: please use UIDatepicker's for entering the Date's rather than manually entering it in the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSDate *today = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"12.12.2013"]; 
    NSDate *newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"13.12.2013"]; 
    NSComparisonResult result; 
    result = [today compare:newDate]; // comparing two dates
    if(result==NSOrderedAscending)  // it checks like this LastDate > FirstDate
        NSLog(@"correct");
    else 
        NSLog(@"error");
```

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel:try like this it'l give your expected answer.

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel:when you compare the dates at that time you can place this code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) for this. You will need to tell the formatter the expected string type then do the conversion.

[Here is a snippet](http://www.crystalminds.nl/archive/site/index.php?p=code-5) for calculating the days in a month as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why let the user enter the date as text? Show a `UIDatePicker` for entry in this field. When the user selects a date, you can use `NSDateFormatter` to show the date in the format you want to. This makes it much less prone to data entry errors.

Comment: UIDatePicker is large for my controller.